# Closure seem to be late on getting variable value after a ajax request on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-deployment

It's seems a little wierd to say, but my code seems to be late on retrieve the variable value when into a loop, only takes the last values. Well, I don't what to say, so here is some piece of code.

```
$("#days").change( function () {
    var num_days  = $('#days').val();
    var URL       = BASE_URL + "/service/assemble_html";
    var languages = ['pt', 'en', 'fr', 'es'];
    var data;

    for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        var lang = languages[i];

        data = {func: 'create_days', data: {days: num_days, lang: lang}};
        console.log(lang);

        // AJAX request, passing the LANG and NUMBER OF DAYS.

        $.post(URL, data, function(response) {
            $('#container_desc_' + lang).html(response);

            console.log("Make it for " + lang);

        });
    }
});
```

... that's my JS/jQuery code. This request is returning (verify on the browser response) a HTML code block for each one of the 4 given languages. Everything whent better then expected so far... BUT, in the part `$('container_desc_' + lang)` it should include the HTML code generated for a container different, given by the `lang` variable. But, isn't working! It's working for the last element of the array, in this case 'es'.

Here my console output:

```
pt                     create.js:12
en                     create.js:12
fr                     create.js:12
es                     create.js:12
Make it for es         create.js:19
Make it for es         create.js:19 
Make it for es         create.js:19
Make it for es         create.js:19
```

... does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

closures and scope:

```
$("#days").change( function () {
    var num_days  = $('#days').val();
    var URL       = BASE_URL + "/service/assemble_html";
    var languages = ['pt', 'en', 'fr', 'es'];

    for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        var lang = languages[i],
            data = {func: 'create_days', data: {days: num_days, lang: lang}};

        (function(l,d) {
            $.post(URL, d, function(response) {
                $('#container_desc_' + l).html(response);
            });
        }(lang, data));
    }
});
```

The `for` loop has completed by the time the callback function is executed, as it's async, so you need to keep the value of the variables constant with a new closure.

Comment: OMG... of course! It's so obvious now! Since it's an asynchronous request, the value can't be used 'real time'! Thank you... thank you so much, mainly for the (really)quick answer!

Comment: ... if ain't any abuse of your good will, could explian whats up with the `function(l, d) {} (lang, data));`  or tell me the name of this tecnique(?)?? It has worked, but still a lack of understandment about your answer.

Comment: It's just a function that executes immediately (IIFE), but passing the variables to the function and "capturing" them as arguments makes them local to that function only, so they keep their value as the loop progresses, otherwise they would be overwritten, and by the time the ajax callback executes, the `lang` variable would only contain the last value from the loop. There's some more on MDN on [**closures**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)